# Why can't I initialize WNDCLASSEX wc?

Tags: c++, initialization, directx-9

I declare the attribute `WNDCLASSEX wc` in my header file like so:

```
private:
    HWND hWnd;
    LPDIRECT3D9 g_pD3D; // Used to create the D3DDevice
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 g_pd3dDevice; // Our rendering device
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
```

And I want to initialize it in my Init() function, like so:

```
void RAT_RendererDX9::Init(RAT_WindowManager* argWMan)
{
    wMan = argWMan;

    // Register the window class
    wc  =
    {
        sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0, 0,
        GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        "D3D Tutorial", NULL
    };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

       hWnd = CreateWindow( "", "abc", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 10, 10, 20, 20,
                     NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );

        g_pD3D = (LPDIRECT3D9)Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
        ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof( d3dpp ) );
        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

    g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                              D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                              &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice );
}
```

However, I get the following errors because of it:

> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_rendererdx9.cpp(18): error
> C2059: syntax error : '{'
>
> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_rendererdx9.cpp(18): error
> C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_rendererdx9.cpp(19): error
> C3867: 'RAT_ENGINE::RAT_RendererDX9::MsgProc': function call missing
> argument list; use '&RAT_ENGINE::RAT_RendererDX9::MsgProc' to create a
> pointer to member
>
> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_rendererdx9.cpp(22): error
> C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

But I practically copied that initialization from the tutorial, with the only exception that wc is initialized in the WinMain() function, instead of an Init() function.

Why isn't it working and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax works for *copy-initializing* an aggregate, but yours is actually an *assignment*. The object `wc` gets default-constructed when you execute the constructor of your `RAT_RendererDX9` class.

The assignment in your `Init` function is actually equivalent to this:

```
wc.operator = (...);
```

If you want to use that syntax, you could try changing your assignment into the following:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass =
{
    sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0, 0,
    GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "D3D Tutorial", NULL
};

wc = wndClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { NULL };
```

Comment: You should give some explanation to what your answer does and why it solves the problem.