# C2440 for overloaded function MsgProc

Tags: c++, directx-9

This is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739385/why-cant-i-initialize-wndclassex-wc/14739467) question.

I have the following assignment:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass =
{
    sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0, 0,
    GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "D3D Tutorial", NULL
};
wc = wndClass;
```

Which gives me the following error:

> 1>e:\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_engine\rat_rendererdx9.cpp(19): error
>   C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to
>   'WNDPROC'
>
> 1>None of the functions with this name in scope
>   match the target type

With MsgProc underlined as the cause, it should reference the following function:

```
LRESULT WINAPI RAT_RendererDX9::MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            CleanUp();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            Render();
            ValidateRect( hWnd, NULL );
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}
```

In the tutorial it works like this and I have copied it almost exactly. So where does the error come from and how can I fix it?

edit:

The declaration of MsgProc is:

```
private:
    LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
```

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `MsgProc` please?

Comment: The window procedure cannot be a C++ class instance function, you must declare it static.  That's probably going to generate a flurry of new compile errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your declaration of `MsgProc` it seems that it's a regular member function, which means it takes a "hidden" `this` pointer. That makes it incompatible with WNDPROC and that's why the compiler complains.

Trying marking it as `static`. Of course, this means that you cannot access non-static members of the class easily - you will need to stash a copy of the `this` pointer of the instance you want somewhere to do that.

You may also need `CALLBACK` instead of `WINAPI` but I don't have easy access to a compiler to verify this at this time.

Comment: It seems to me that I need a class to use my `CleanUp()` and `Render()` functions, but to use them in `MsgProc()` I'll need to make them static as well. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you can "stash" a copy of the `this` pointer somewhere (perhaps in a map mapping an `HWND` to a `RAT_RendererDX9 *`?) then you can retrieve it and use it to call `CleanUp()` and `Render()` using the regular function-call syntax (i.e. `ptr->CleanUp()`)

Comment: I can't seem to envision this. Could you give me a code example?

Comment: Without knowing more about your particular implementation, I cannot easily give you one. But the idea is to make it so your static window procedure can retrieve the `RAT_RendererDX9` with which a particular message is associated, then it can simply call the member functions on that instance. Do you foresee having multiple `RAT_RendererDX9` instances active at any one time? If not, then you could use a singleton (or make everything static... ick!). If yes, you'll need a more advanced technique.

Comment: For now I'll probably only use one implementation of the Renderer, so I'll go with the singleton for now.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems most elegant if you bind the instance/object of your class to the HWND. To set and retrieve the pointer to your instance, you can use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx)/[`GetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx).

So after creating your window, you call

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, static_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));
```

And in your `WindowProcedure`, you call

```
YourClass* instance = static_cast<YourClass*> (GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
```

Be careful in the `WindowProcedure`: It already gets called when you create the window but obviously, you can only call `SetWindowLongPtr` afterwards. So, when your `WindowProcedure` gets called first, `GetWindowLongPtr` will fail. Make sure, that the function even works in these cases.